# Trying to make xml data readable for Arcgis

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am trying to convert xml data into tabular form for the process of geocoding.  We have the xml file with info that we are going to run through an address locator.  Do I need a script for this? Can we import directly into arc without coverting to xls, maybe using Python?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the process can be scripted. To build one. the best how-to walk through ive seen is.
http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html

Doug builds a xml to csv script and explains the process well.

If this process is something your going to do/rerun often consider a look at FME, it has excellent XML to *.* tools.

but if a one off is needed. there is 
http://www.xml-converter.com/
to be honest I have not tried the converter tool, but looks promising